# Is there a way to notify me whenever someone edited a page I made?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm new in mediawiki and I want to know if is there a way to notify me whenver someone edited something on a page I created. Watchlist is okay but I need a more user friendly approach. Echo (Notification extension for mediawiki) doesn't seem to support this kind of feature.

Comment: What do you mean "Watchlist is okay but I need a more user friendly approach."  What more do you want than emailing you when someone edits the page?

Comment: I mean, is there a way to really notify you if a page you created has been modified. Like facebook notification. Echo extension is perfect but it does not support that kind of feature yet.

Comment: You can set a watch on any page including those that you have created.  Or are you asking "Can I make it automatically set a watch on any page that I create"?

Comment: Yes, you can set what page you want to watch, BUT you can't be notified (not email notify) if an edit has been made on the page you are watching. You still have to go to the watchlist page.

Comment: Are you saying you CAN'T get email when a watched page changes?  There is an option "E-mail me when a page on my watchlist is changed" on the first page of the Preferences page, under "E-mail options".  Or are you saying you want something other than email?

Comment: I want something other than email. Like echo, when someone thanks you or someone links your page to another page. I like something like that on the watchlist

Comment: You can create/extend the code to Echo to do this.

Comment: @mateeyow, why isn't Special:Watchlist ok? Do you want the personal tools (the top bar in Vector) to change graphically in some way?

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the MediaWiki core method is to [watch the pages and enable notifications in your preferences](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Watching_pages#Email_notification). Default settings should suffice in recent MediaWiki releases.

As for having a graphical alert to make you visit Special:Watchlist when there are updates, indeed [this feature has been requested discussed before](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T97885), but doesn't exist yet.